# Can SonarQube really detect memory leaks?

Tags: memory-leaks, sonarqube, sonarscanner, bandit-python, semgrep

I'm using SonarQube (v8.9) at work with SonarScanner (v4.2).

I've created two memory leaks, one in Javascript and one in Python. They couldn't be detected from SonarScanner.

These are the snippets:

JS:

```
beforeMount () {
  Window.test = {
    name: 'home',
    node: document.getElementById('home')
  }
}
```

Python:

```
import requests
import gc
 
def call():
  response = requests.get('https://google.com')
  print("Status code", response.status_code)
  return
 
 
def main():
  print("No.of tracked objects before calling get method")
  print(len( gc.get_objects() ) )
  call()
 
  print("No.of tracked objects after calling get method")
  print(len( gc.get_objects() ) )
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

The questions are:

- Can SonarQube/SonarScanner detect memory leaks?
- Can a static analyzer detect memory leaks? (Neither Bandit nor Semgrep could detect these)
- Do you have examples of snippets of code that create memory leaks that I can use to test?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think either of these have a memory leak? Both Python and Javascript have automatic memory management, and the garbage collector is going to handle this.